# EF query "randomly" returns either no results or correct result

Tags: sql, entity-framework, logging

Calling simple select with inner join causes to return 2 different scenarios.

Either it returns the set with all data or returns no data.
This will work 100% when running locally (so unable to trace it while debugging the code).

Running sql profiler I was unable to figure out the difference (executing both queries will return correct data each time).

Even used DbContextDatabase.Log => eventLog.WriteEntry() to log it.

I can see the query and all the params passed ok. The only difference is log (right before connection closed)
-- Completed in xx ms with result: SqlDataReader (when data are returned) vs
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader (with no data returned)

I can provide more details if needed

IN:
Datetime dtDate;
int compId;

OUT:
List<Table_1DTO>

query:

```
result = (from x in Database.Table_1.AsNoTracking()
              .Where(a => dtDate < (a.EndDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow)&& a.StartDate <= dtDate && a.CompanyId == compId)
          from y in Database.Table_2
              .Where(b => b.Id == x.CId && dtDate < (b.EndDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow)&& dtDate > b.StartDate && b.SiteID == compId)

      select new Table_1DTO
      {
          ID = x.ID,
          CompanyId = x.CompanyId,
          col1 = x.col1,
          col2 = x.col2,
          col3 = x.col3,
          col4 = x.col4,
          col5 = x.col5,
          col6 = x.col6,
          CId = x.CId,
          CategoryName = y.CategoryName 
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: You will need to provide a minimal reproduceable example before anyone can help you. From what you do describe I would look at restoring a db backup from an affected environment to debug against. I would also look at the way your joins are configured as it is pretty easy to misconfigure relationships that appear to work in a limited and controlled test environment where IDs can overlap and appear to be working, but then in a production environment with considerably more data, those mismatched relationships either return wrong data, or appear to be missing all-together.

Comment: I cannot really provide reproduceable example because I can't find one. Db was recently restored but I will restore it again. As far as different environment, we have 4 (if you count local as 1). Prod,UAT,Dev. Dev being the only issue.

Comment: I have checked if there were any differences (scripted CREATE for affected table) and all are identical. While testing we started off with no data (saving new records works) I will post the query

Comment: So if it works in Prod, but not in Dev and you have run the generated SQL against the Dev DB and it seems to return the expected results, then the leading culprit I can think of is that at runtime your DbContext connection string isn't pointing at the database instance it should be.  If "Database" is your DbContext in EF6, capture the connection string using `Database.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`. For EF Core use `Database.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString`. If you cannot reproduce while debugging, output that to somewhere you can inspect.

Comment: @StevePy would the connection string change at random? On random (wasn't able to figure out the pattern) it works in dev as well. Either using page reload or grid refresh (using kendo MVC grid) both calling the same method I get expected result after "random number" refresh clicks. looking at the profiler both records show same dbid (assuming that creates connection to same db). The only difference there was that the bad call was return after 0ms vs xxms